# Responsive divs width and height with css

Tags: css, layout, resize, horizontal-scrolling

I am trying to build a horizontal scrolling layout, composed of image blocks:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300">
 </div>
   <div class="item">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
 </div>
   <div class="item">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
 </div>
</div>
```

I used `display:inline-block` and  `white-space: nowrap;` properties to achieve this, and it does work but browsers don't seem to recompute block widths on resize?

Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/g597w3Lr/2/ and try resizing the browser..

Here is a screen grab to better understand what is my problem:
https://youtu.be/VxKo4gysc1o

1. At first all images are well positioned and i can scroll horizontally: perfect.
2. I then resize the browser
3. images are resizing, not the `.item` wrappers. White gaps appear :(

Basically i was expecting same feature as with vertical scrolling, i.e. adapting width depending on content size.
I actually dont even understand the logic here..

Is there any way to get over this?

Thanks!

Comment: My apologies I am having trouble understanding your issue. Although width of your first image is 200px, if you re-size the browser, it changes according to the browser. Is it what are you trying to fix? Are you expecting it to be 200px despite of the browser size? Please clarify.

Comment: If you resize the browser horizontally you will see the image resize but not its wrapping block (.item)? (on chrome/firefox)

Comment: @skiplecariboo i think this is what you seek as result clearing the whitegaps on resize , https://jsfiddle.net/g597w3Lr/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37115072/2)*

---

**EDIT 2:** Looking at your video I think the new approach is what you are looking for.

You have to display your `divs` with `.item` class as `inline` and remove your `white-space: normal` property.

```
.item {
  display: inline;
  height:100%;
}
```

[**Updated JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/g597w3Lr/8/).

## Explanation:

*I am not an expert of `CSS` so if someone see some mistake please correct me.*

When you display an element as `inline-block` as the [official documentation](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/display#Values) says:

> - inline-block
>
> Causes an element to generate an inline-level block container. **The inside of an inline-block is formatted as a block box**, and the element itself is formatted as an atomic inline-level box.

which means that the element that you display as `inline-block` acts like a block but you can set it inline (in the same line). This means that you can set a div (which is `display: block` as default) in a single line. You can also see it [here](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Generic_containers_-_the_div_and_span_elements#Inline_versus_block):

> The div element, short for division, is the block level generic container.

Also, `inline` elements cannot get `height/width` properties so this is the reason why when you display your `divs` with `.item` class as `inline`, they wrap the content but not get the `height/width` that they should correspond to take (from their parents in your case, as you put them with `%`).

If you display them as `inline-block` it does not changes anything about their default `height/width` properties. Just allows you to display them in a single line.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emv1dhxu/1/) to see the three divs (`inline`/ `inline-block` / `block`, as default).

Comment: i actually want the items to overflow to create a horizontal scrolling layout. My issue is that the items width do not resize correctly when the browser is resized vertically.

Comment: @skiplecariboo What do you exactly mean with _that the items width do not resize correctly_?

Comment: thanks for helping :) I mean that images are resizing, but the wrappers (.item class) do not resize. You can see white gaps between images. I updated my question with a video screengrab, hope that helps!

Comment: @skiplecariboo So what you want is that the wrappers also resize?

Comment: yes :) this is what i expected, so that each image stay next to each other without white gaps.

Comment: @Error404 that last edit like i did 2 update ago. we edit and edit not clear what we need to do!

Comment: yes i saw it. i don't know that's what skiplecariboo wants.

Comment: This is it! thanks @Error404, .item blocks are now resizing properly. I will check it in depth to give you the bounty. Also i am very sorry, i realize i didnt explain my problem  really well..

Comment: @skiplecariboo I have added an explanation to my answer. I expect it will be helpful for you :)

Comment: Simple and objective answer. Useful for my resolution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will have to modify slightly your css

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300">
 </div>
   <div class="item">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
 </div>
   <div class="item">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body {
  height:auto;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height:auto;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
}

.item img {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g597w3Lr/9/)

Answer (score 0):

check it see that's what you want ?

I manage your classes with border:solid 1px red;
and use width:100% in some classes.

also in class item:

```
width:100%;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g597w3Lr/6/

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the .item elements do not have the same width necessarily, i would like to use images with different ratio. In your example images are stretched :-/

Comment: @skiplecariboo Do you have always same images, same sizes ? if we responsive all div, some images will stretch. and not looking good.

Comment: the layout should accept different images with different sizes. They are resized driven by the height that should alway fit the browser heught. Width is free. No stretching.